# Accessing variable in Smarty Array

Tags: multidimensional-array, smarty

I'm trying to access a variable in a smarty array.  The array is called product and contains loads of values.  A print_r dump of the array is shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 4
            [productid] => 31
            [productcode] => 1658303
            [product] => ENERGIZER 628504 COMP RECHARGABLE TORCH
            [provider] => master
            [distribution] => 
            [weight] => 0.00
            [list_price] => 29.80
            [descr] => Torches
            [fulldescr] => Energizer Rechargeable Emergency Torch Complete With Krypton Bulb
            [avail] => 6
            [rating] => 2
            [forsale] => Y
            [add_date] => 0
            [views_stats] => 1
            [sales_stats] => 0
            [del_stats] => 0
            [shipping_freight] => 0.00
            [free_shipping] => N
            [discount_avail] => Y
            [min_amount] => 1
            [length] => 0.00
            [width] => 0.00
            [height] => 0.00
            [low_avail_limit] => 10
            [free_tax] => N
            [product_type] => N
            [manufacturerid] => 0
            [return_time] => 0
            [keywords] =>  
            [meta_description] => 
            [meta_keywords] => 
            [small_item] => N
            [separate_box] => N
            [items_per_box] => 1
            [title_tag] => 
            [orderid] => 2
            [price] => 11.96
            [amount] => 2
            [product_options] => 
            [extra_data] => Array
                (
                    [product_options] => 
                    [taxes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [display] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 11.96
                            [discounted_price] => 23.92
                            [subtotal] => 23.92
                        )

                )

            [is_deleted] => 
            [returns] => 
            [extra_fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fieldid] => 1
                            [provider] => master
                            [field] => ESW Carbon Points
                            [value] => 50
                            [active] => Y
                            [orderby] => 1
                            [service_name] => SERVICE_NAME01
                            [productid] => 31
                        )

                )

            [display_price] => 11.96
            [display_discounted_price] => 23.92
            [display_subtotal] => 23.92
            [product_options_txt] => 
            [ordered_price] => 11.96
            [original_price] => 11.96
            [price_deducted_tax] => Y
        )

)
```

I want to access the "value" field within the extra fields array but I don't understand what the syntax is to get to it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{$var[0].extra_fields[0].value}
```

Comment: What you've written makes perfect sense to me and I'm sure it would work normally but it doesn't for me.  I think it is to do with the way the application I'm using processes the smarty variables between where I did the print_r and where I'm trying to output the variable.

Anyway, your suggested solution did put me on the right track to get things working, I was just trying to approach it in a way too complicated manner.  So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`{$var.0.extra_fields.0.value}`